# Export content from Mura CMS

Tags: coldfusion, content-management-system, mura

Has anyone worked on Mura CMS before? I need to know if it is possible to export a Mura site into HTML, XML so that I can import it into some other CMS (mostly Wordpress)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Mura 5.4+, there's a BETA feature you can try:

1) Login to the Admin, then go to Site Settings
2) Select the site you wish to export
3) On the Basic tab, scroll to the bottom and enter a directory to export static HTML files to (i.e., C:\sitefiles\ )
4) Click Update
5) Select the site again from the list of Current Sites
6) You should now see a link towards the top that reads 'Export Static HTML (BETA)'
7) Click the link and you should get an alert 'Export static HTML files to {whateverDirectoryYouEnteredEarlier}

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also export a "[Site Bundle](http://docs.getmura.com/installation-set-up/site-settings/site-bundles/)" from the Site Settings. The Site Bundle will have all of the content of the site wrapped in nice WWDX XML files, that you could then parse with any language to import into another system.